# One of the possible reason for slow android studio and RAM consumption

Tags: java, android, android-studio, memory

I have been facing slow performance of Android Studio in past couple of months.

Here is my system configuration :

> Intel® Core™ i5-4460 CPU @ 3.20GHz × 4, RAM 7.7 GiB + 1 GB nvdia 210(i am not sure about nvdia)

I was checking mt system performance using **htop**

here is the response generate when my system lags:

[image]

in this image it clearly says something is not working appropriately. 
I kill the process of open-jdk and there is no effect on the android studio AFAIK and however RAM reduced significanly.

here is the screenshot when i kill the 43.4G process

[image]

As you can see in the screenshot after killing openjdk there is another java present.

I tried this `update-java-alternatives -l` and found these results:

```
java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64 1071 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64
java-8-oracle 1073 /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
```

Is there any problem if i keep two java jdk. I think at runtime both the process were runnning which creates the problem.

Please let me what wrong with the system that flood the RAM.

If you require anything please let me know so that question remain clear.

If i need system upgradation what is the major factor to change like processor or RAM.

**EDITED**

I have removed open-jdk from my system and set jdk to oracle

[image]

But still i am getting 43.5G virtual memory consumption during project build.

[image]

What is the problem. Why system works fine and after some time RAM is consumed significantly and systems hangs

Comment: Please comment for -1

Comment: If you want i can close the question but do give me a reason

Comment: "Is there any problem if i keep two java jdk" -- I would not expect a problem for you to have more than one installed. However, I would recommend that you try to settle on using one at a time with Android Studio and Gradle. Google prefers the `oracle` builds over the `openjdk` builds for Android Studio. Make sure that your `java` command runs the same JDK that is configured for use inside of Android Studio, and see if that at least limits your Java processes to either `oracle` or `openjdk` and not both.

Comment: "If i need system upgradation what is the major factor to change like processor or RAM." I can tell you now you won't solve this by adding another 43.4GB RAM or upgrading CPU, which is good news for you!

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks i will remove open-jdk from my system. Lets hope performance upgrade to optimal.

Comment: @CommonsWare  please check edits.. Removing open-jdk don't solve my problem.

Comment: @weston what is the reason behind so much RAM consumption is that optimal

Comment: Please use punctuation. I presume you are asking me: "What is the reason behind so much RAM consumption? Is that optimal?" No it's not optimal, and I have no idea why your computer is doing that. I was just saying you can *not* and should *not* solve it by beefing up the computer.

Comment: you can buy more RAM and a new cpu, i think that will help you :)
keep the chrome and firefox close when you are running emulator and android studio, i think that will you too

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have upgraded my ram and i am able run my projects easily. Android studio consumes a lot of RAM.